# Android - Correlate specific fingerprint with application

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

I have a question regarding fingerprint authentication.

I know that my application should and can't access the fingerprints registered or any information whatsoever.

The [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html) class only exposes the hasEnrolledFingerprints() and authenticates with any of the enrolled ones.

So if I want only a specific user that has activated the fingerprint to associate said fingerprint with his/hers device for my application, is there any way to do it? Basically I want to restrict the application to a subset (one in this case) of the enrolled fingerprints.

As a workaround, I could use the count of the enrolled fingerprints and disable this type of authentication for my app if more than one exist.

Many thanks!